# Django: Best way to render model instances based on authorization

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to ask you about a recommendation how to solve this issue I'm struggling right now. My objective is to have a simple page which renders my model instances one after another, but based on the user it should skip certain instances.

**models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
        creator= models.ForeignKey(User,null=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        private = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=True, default=False)
```

**views.py**

```
def topics(request):
    items=Item.objects.all()
    context={'items' : items}
    return render(request, 'items.html', context)
```

**main.html**

```
    {% for item in items %}
    <div>    
    <p>{{item.title}}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

**Question:**
If 'private' is true I want to skip that item if the user is not staff. This way I can separate the items based on this boolean. What is the recommended/best way to do that?
I don't want a if/else statement in html and then repeat the code. It's getting a messy as the project grows.

Thanks in advance!

## One possible solution:

The answer of @Eugenij gave me the idea to filter in `views.py`. I just check the authorization in an if statement and return a query set based on that.
I mean it works fine, but since I'm new to Django I'll still appreciate other inputs.

**views.py**

```
def topics(request):

if request.user.is_staff == True:
        items=Item.objects.all()
else:
        items=Item.objects.filter(private=False)
        
context={'items' : items}
return render(request, 'items.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that there is some common approaches for function-based views.

In [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) you can create custom [Filter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering) and include it to your [ViewSets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) It looks like this

```
class BaseKeyFilter(BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        if not request.user.is_staff:
            queryset = queryset.filter(private=False)
        return queryset
            
class ItemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serialiser = ItemSerializer
    filter_backends = [BaseKeyFilter]
```

With your approach you can function like this

```
def filter_private(request, queryset):
    if not request.user.is_staff:
        queryset = queryset.filter(private=False)
    return queryset
```

And use it like this

```
def topics(request):
    items=Item.objects.all()
    items=filter_private(request, items)
    context={'items' : items}
    return render(request, 'items.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer, I'm not familiar with DRF that's why I prefer a pure django way I wrote above for now.

Comment: @danbrae You can use `def filter_private(request, queryset):` and `def topics(request):` from my example without DRF. So, you can eliminate `if` statement from view.